# SQL SELECT CASE

Tags: sql, oracle, case

There is a table: `Emp( EmpId, EmpName, Sal )`

I have to display all the data of the table along with bonus calculated using the following information:

```
          sal >  5000, bonus = 10%
          sal > 10000, bonus = 20%
          sal > 25000, bonus = 30%
```

with in a single query.

Comment: What code have you done so far?

Comment: @whoever voted to close this question as "Unclear what you are asking" - please share what you have found unclear about this question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CASE expression:

```
select empid, empname, sal,
       case 
          when sal > 25000 then sal * 0.30 
          when sal > 10000 then sal * 0.20
          when sal >  5000 then sal * 0.10
          else 0
       end as bonus
from emp;
```

Comment: I suspect bonus = 30% means `sal * 0.30` rather than `30` :-)

Comment: @subhamoymaitra - Note that the order of the `when... then...` pairs is crucial. They are evaluated in the order they are written, if the first `when` condition fails the next one is tested, and as soon as the first successful `when` is found, the corresponding `then` part is executed and the `case` expression is done. (If no `when` condition is satisfied, then the value in the `else` clause is used; `else` is optional, if it is omitted and execution gets that far, the default value is `null`.) Exercise: what happens if you put the `when sal > 5000...` comparison first?